# Windows Store Apps unavailable in VS 2015 RC

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-store-apps, visual-studio-2015

I am trying to create my first Store app for Windows 8.

I installed VS2015 RC and the [Windows Software Development](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/bg162891.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) Kit for Windows 8 (I followed the instructions [at this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211384.aspx#Started)).
Unfortunately I can't see the *Windows Apps* templates in VS, differently from what the link shows [image: Store Apps templates].

I am running VS2015 Enterprise RC on a Windows 7 machine.

What am I missing? Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Minimum required OS for developing Windows Store Apps is Windows 8. With Windows 7 you wont be able to develop Store apps.